# AJAX Autocomplete from an SQL table?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, autocomplete

*Hi.*

How am I able to have an input that will autocomplete based on information from an SQL table?

**What I have tried:**

```
  [CSS]
  [JQUERY]
  <script>
$( function() {
var availableTags = [
<?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '"'.$row["user_username"].'",';
        }
    }
?>
  ];
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
} );
  </script>


<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

This works, but when I try add a:

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM table";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '"'.$row["username"].'",<br>';
    }
}
```

Instead of the JS list of "Username 1" etc, it will not work.

**How can I use PHP to select the usernames for the list of autocomplete statements (Username 1, Username 2 etc)?**

This can be rephrased as "How can I echo PHP from an SQL query in a JS array?"

*Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.*

Comment: Where exactly the `php` code gets inside the `javascript` code?

Comment: remove the <br/> tag

Comment: assuming you're using the jquery UI autocomplete package?  You can't 'echo PHP from an SQL query in a JS array'. You CAN use JS to make a request to a URL that will return JSON data for use in your autocompleter.

Comment: @jcorry, thats not correct. Sure you can do that.

Comment: oh right...people still embed PHP in their pages. Your best bet then would be to get the results from the query and json_encode it.
`var avaliableTags = <?= json_encode(array_values($result->fetch_assoc())); ?>;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're making it complicated. Here you only need the PHP array to be in JS variable.

So,

`var usernames = <?= json_encode($arr) ?>;`

or

`var usernames = <?php echo json_encode($arr) ?>;`

would be fine.

```
<?php

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $usernames[] = $row["user_username"];
        }
    }

?>

<script>
    var usernames = <?= json_encode($usernames); ?>
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: usernames
    });
</script>
```

Hope you got the solution.